# Value of type 'UITouch' has no member 'locationInNode'

Tags: ios, swift2, uitouch, touchesbegan

I'm trying to get location of touch with swift2.1 and get error "Value of type 'UITouch' has no member 'locationInNode'".

here is my code

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        print(location)
    }
}
```

I had a look into source and saw that in class UITouch there is only public

```
func locationInView(view: UIView?) -> CGPoint {
}
```

is it something I should use or ... ?

Comment: Under the section "Working with Touch Events in SpriteKit" there is `locatonInNode()` (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITouch_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITouch/locationInNode:). Perhaps you need to `import SpriteKit`?

Comment: thanks NicolasMiari, got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As NicolasMiari pointed out in the comment, only if you are using `SpriteKit` this will work. `locationInNode()` is a `SpriteKit` function that helps you find the point in an `SKNode`.

If you are using "standard" `UIKit` where you want to get the location of a touch in a view, you should be using `locationInView()` which takes a view(!) not the controller itself.

```
class ViewController : UIViewController{

  override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
      let location = touch.locationInView(self.view)
      print(location)
    }
  }

}
```